# Unity - admob - Gradle Failed to fetch dependencies error

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, admob

I m following admob interstitial ad tutorial.I imported plugin.When try to resolve android play services I m getting these error.

Error 1:

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:LogMissingDependenciesError(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey18:<>m__26(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Error2 :

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'C:\Users\batuhan osma\Documents\dart2d\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat -b "C:\Users\batuhan osma\Documents\dart2d\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" --no-daemon "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\batuhan osma\Documents\dart2d\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.2.2"'
stdout:

stderr:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\batuhan osma\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.2.1-bin\dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju\gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @SaraKat probably I have not been. I suggest you google the error, there are many stackoverflow questions with answers and also some posts in unity forum